# Suggestion for open source software to create a voice chat application

Tags: api, web-applications, voip, voice

Looking to create a voice application to work with 10 computers and 1 server connected locally.(offline) I'm thinking the server would hold the application and the computers would run clients.

Ideally there would be a total of 10 channels that users can join or leave.

I'm looking for open source applications or APIs that I can utilize for this. Are there any suggestions of prewritten code I can utilize and create a custom GUI?

I'm looking to create something similar to ventrillo but have the ability to customize the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You can use asterisk with app_conference or webrtc and some MCU.

But anyway you will not get even close to ventrillo. Ventrillo's main complexity is not conference itself, but noise supression/voice detection and choose of correct codec for each channel acordinly to current bandwidth.